# Is Matrix EE1 still available somewhere?

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic, ee1, bulk

I would like to use the fieldframe FF Matrix Bulk/Multiple Upload. Is there any way I can acquire Matrix version 1.3.5 or newer so I can use the Bulk add on?

Answer (score 6):

Pixel and Tonic obliged me with this request recently. Just [purchase a license for Matrix](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix), then email them to request the last available EE1-compatible version (I believe it's 2.5.3).

Comment: You're welcome. To "accept" an answer, click the checkmark icon next to it.